# How do I make a task run on startup through raimeter?

Tags: rainmeter

I want a random number to be generated every time I start my computer so I can randomly choose a background on rainmeter. Every time I try to search for an answer I keep getting pages for how to make rainmeter run on startup.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [RunCommand](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/plugins/runcommand/) plugin to execute a command line input.
To make it run once when the skin is loaded, you just need to set option `UpdateDivider=-1`.
The following opens Notepad on startup, replace it in `Parameter=Notepad` with the command you wish to run.

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=1000

[MeasureRunCmd]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=RunCommand
Parameter=Notepad

[MeterRunCmd]
UpdateDivider=-1
Meter=String
Text=None
OnUpdateAction=[!CommandMeasure MeasureRunCmd "Run"]
```

If you don't need the extra flexibility of that plugin you can just use the following

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=1000

[MeterRunCmd]
UpdateDivider=-1
Meter=String
Text=None
OnUpdateAction=["Notepad"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I just became acquainted with Rainmeter about 3 hours ago. But here's a thought:

Any "app" (or even a shortcut to an app) that's in "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" will run at ... uhh? ... STARTUP! (that's it!). Now, since cmd.exe runs as conhost.exe before the startup folder is processed, that means we can use the "DOS" (I'm an old fart) %RANDOM% variable.

So, if Rainmeter can handle system variables in ".ini" files then you can use %Random% directly (Enter %RANDOM% at the command prompt and you'll see a different number returned everytime). Also, Google %RANDOM% (case, like size, does matter) to see the tweaks used to get any range of numbers you desire.

If Rainmeter can't handle system variables directly then write a 1 line ".bat" file that "set"s the random number to a string (or whatever you can use) and stick the batch file (or a shortcut to it) in the startup folder.

I can't think of a reason why this easy method (or your own enhanced version of it) won't work.

Good luck. Interesting idea. Let me know how you make out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future, you should put variables in backticks so it's formatted as code to make your question and answers easier to read.

Comment: Yes, but I used the format that cmd.exe and Windows understands. I didn't present and real code.